# ember/rails app loading not loading properly (takes too long) in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, loading

i have a new ember-cli app with rails backend. it is taking about 30+ seconds to load in development... which is obviously way too long.

i am using the ember-cli-rails gem https://github.com/rwz/ember-cli-rails

i'm using the rails server (i've tried webrick and thin). i'm not using ember server, not running them separately.

i am not using the rails asset pipeline. i have deleted it.

here is my rails config/routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :rewrites, contraints: { format: :json }
  resources :users, contraints: { format: :json }
  resources :movies, contraints: { format: :json }

  root 'application#index'

  namespace :api do
    get :csrf, to: 'csrf#index'
  end

  get "/*path" => "application#index", contraints: { format: :html }
```

here is my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Better Films</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

here is my application/index.html.erb, frontend is the name of my ember app

```
<%= include_ember_script_tags :frontend %>
<%= include_ember_stylesheet_tags :frontend %>
```

when i go to localhost, my rails server log shows this

```
Rendered application/index.html.erb within layouts/application (173.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 203ms (Views: 202.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/frontend/frontend.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-15 23:13:28 -0600


Started GET "/assets/frontend/vendor.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-15 23:13:39 -0600


Started GET "/assets/frontend/frontend.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-15 23:13:49 -0600


Started GET "/assets/frontend/vendor.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-15 23:14:00 -0600
```

web inspector network tab shows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related, but I had the same issue when I set the ember app's path in `config/initializers/ember.rb` to `Rails.root.join('frontend').to_s`. When I removed the path option, everything worked fine.